# Wrong utf8 character output savexml and tcpdf

Tags: php, utf-8, svg, tcpdf

Hi i'm using TCPDF to load an svg file, manipulate it and send it as pdf.

The svg file contain utf8 characters and after saving it the utf8 characters don't show properly.

Here is the svg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="742" id="svg_area" shape-rendering="crispEdges" title="test" viewport-fill="" viewport-fill-opacity="0" width="1042" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<defs id="4D"/>
<g Cbarre="2" id="Image_DBB524BDFDFB4E4180B8BB48EF3F68CC" transform="rotate(0,176.5,522)">
    <text font-family="arial" font-size="14" height="20" id="txtImage_DBB524BDFDFB4E4180B8BB48EF3F68CC" visibility="visible" x="404" y="435" ztspan="1">
    <tspan>äëïòû</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And the php code :

```
 // create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'UTF-8', false);

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 5, true);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language dependent data:
$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);
//$source : path to svg file
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($source);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// set orientation
$page = $dom->getElementsByTagName('svg')->item(0);
$width_page = $page->getAttribute('width');
$height_page = $page->getAttribute('height');
$orientation = 'L';
if($width_page < $height_page){
    $orientation = 'P';
}

// add a page  
$pdf->AddPage($orientation, '', false, false);    


//modify dom svg for variable
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $gNodes=$xpath->query('//*[@id=\'' . $key . '\']');
    foreach ($gNodes as $gNode) {
        // doing stuff with $gNode
        $gNode->nodeValue = $value;
    }
 }   
$txt = '@'.$dom->saveXml();
$pdf->ImageSVG($txt, $x=0, $y=0, $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=true);
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('utf8.pdf', 'I');
```

The pdf file after treatment show wrong utf-8 character : i'm expecting "äëïòû" in the pdf and i get "Ã¤Ã«Ã¯Ã²Ã»".
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Its hard to tell for sure what the problem might be. What is displayed in the PDF and what are you expecting?

Comment: Hi, i'm expecting : "äëïòû" in the pdf and i get "Ã¤Ã«Ã¯Ã²Ã»".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'UTF-8', false);
```

should be:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

If you are going to be using a unicode encoding, the unicode parameter should be set to true.  Assuming your SVG file is properly saved as UTF-8, it should work as you expect with this change.